# Sorting an ArrayList on a child's value in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, sorting

I have an `ArrayList` that contains multiple `String[]` (String arrays).

Each `String[]` contains a key: `name`

What I want to do is sort the `ArrayList` based on the value of `name`.

Using `Array.Sort` did not work because it cannot compare `String[]`. How can I sort the `ArrayList` based on the value of `name` that is within the `String[]`?

Comment: Why ArrayList? I have never seen a scenario where List<T> didn't serve the purpose.

Comment: Is the key the first element in each of the `Array[]`'s?  If so, you could always use LINQ.

Comment: Yes it's always the first element, but not the only one.

Comment: Why does it matter whether I use `ArrayList` or `List`? The sorting problem still exists no?

Comment: Yes, but it is simpler with `List`.

Comment: I believe `List` is strongly typed (meaning the compiler enforces that only instances of one base type can be placed in the array), whereas `ArrayList` allows any "object" to be placed in it.

Comment: I think Kendall intention is to advertise List<T> ... there are still people, that use ArrayList, because they don't know about List<T> ...

Comment: I remember being disappointed after following the book examples to create a strongly-typed collection class, and then finding out the work was for nothing because of List<>. List<> is a very powerful class.

Comment: Alright, trying with `List` now. Thanks for the help so far.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In LINQ:

```
var ordered = arrayList.Cast<String[]>().OrderBy(ar => arr[0]);
```

Normally it's better to use a strong typed `List<String[]>` instead of an `ArrayList`. When you say *key* it sounds as if you want to have a list of strings for each unique key. Then a `Dictionary<String, String[]>` would be the best choice.

Comment: ArrayList doesn't implement `IEnumerable<T>`. You need `arrayList.Cast<string[]>.OrderBy(arr => arr[0])`;

Comment: Sure, 1 minute. Am I supposed to refresh the page every 10 seconds? :)

Comment: What does `ar` represent in this example? the `string[]` within the list?

Comment: @Pieter888: Sorry, that was a typo :( Corrected. It's the String[]

Comment: You still have a typo `ar(r) => arr[0]`

Comment: Thank you for your fast reply, but I don't understand what you mean with `ar => arr[0]`. The array is filled at another location so I only have the object `MyList`. How do I define those `ar` or `arr`.

Comment: @Pieter888: It doesn't matter where it's defined. You have a reference of it and you want it to be ordered by the first element. That is what i'm doeing here. `ar` is simply a reference to every String-Array in your ArrayList, hence `OrderBy(ar => arr[0])` orders the whole list by the first element in that array. Maybe you need to add `using System.Linq`.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I didn't understand how LINQ worked before but now I understand. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You should be using a `List<string[]>`. It supports everything that `ArrayList` does, and it is strongly typed.

Using a `List<string[]>`:

```
IEnumerable<string[]> sorted = myList.OrderBy(s => s[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
ArrayList arr = new ArrayList();
arr.ToArray().OrderBy(p => p);
```

Comment: I think you may mean `p => p[0]`?

Answer (score 0):

Use [Array.Sort(Array,IComparer)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa311216%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) and write your own Comparer that looks for your key in your String[] and compare them.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an `IComparer` an use

```
public virtual void Sort(
    IComparer comparer
)
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0e743hdt.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can pass to `Array.Sort` either a delegate or a class implementing an interface that implements the custom comparison you need. 
See some examples http://bytes.com/topic/c-sharp/answers/235679-two-dimension-array-sort.